# Unable to resolve NULL driver for [Illuminate\Mail\TransportManager]

Tags: laravel-6, mail

Tengo un problema al enviar correos masivos

```
public function Registro()
{   
    $msj = User::where("rol","=","ALUMNO")->where("password","=",NULL)->where("status_u","=",NULL)->get();
    
      
    foreach ($msj as $msj1 ) {


            $data = [
                'link'          => 'http://localhost:8000/register',
                'nombre'        => $msj1->nombre,
                'n_control'     => $msj1->n_control,
                'texto'         =>'Su alta en el sistema de Buzon del quejas y sugerencias ha sido realizada. Favor de dar clic  en el siguiente enlace para concluir con su registro. '
            ];

            $email = $msj1->email;
            $nombre = $msj1->nombre;
            $template_path = 'email_template3';

            Mail::send(['html'=> $template_path ], $data, function($message) use ($email,$nombre){
                $message->to($email,$nombre)->subject('QUEJA ASIGNADA');
                $message->from('buzonquejas@lcardenas.tecnm.mx','BuzonItlac');
            });

            $data  = array(
                    'status'    =>  'Succes',
                    'code'     =>  '200',
                    'message'  =>  ' REGISTRO ASIGNADO'
                ); 
    }      
}
```

Esto es lo que uso para enviar correos, esta herramienta ya la eh usado para enviar un solo correo, pero quise aplicar un *foreach* para enviar correos masivos y el resultado  fue el siguiente error:

> Unable to resolve NULL driver for [Illuminate\Mail\TransportManager].

Como mencione antes, este método lo use para enviar anteriormente correo pero solo por persona y cuando intento recorrer a los usuarios  y enviarlos  masivamente me sale ese error espero me puedan ayudar, gracias.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con "anteriormente"? ¿Actualmente puedes enviar un email, pero no muchos?

Comment: así es, actualmente puedo enviar un email pero no muchos, y ahora que intento enviar muchos me sale ese error